# Collections - clear()

Tags: java, collections, iterator

I have created a collection and filled it with elements which are collections too, but when I tried to iterate through this container using a `foreach` construction (or other methods) it returns me nothing, I tried to get size() and saw what I expect (appropriate number) but seems like nevertheless container not empty inside each collection is null

**Code snippet example:**

```
Item it1, it2;
List<Collection<Item>> hull = new ArrayList<Collection<Item>>();
List<Item> seq = new ArrayList<Item>();
seq.add(it1);
hull.add(seq);
seq.clear();
seq.add(it2);
hull.add(seq);
for (<Collection<Item> c: hull)
      System.out.println(c);
```

This is just an simplified snippet of what I do
Please suggest alternatives. Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: This code doesn't compile. It lacks `;`, `get(0)` isn't defined on `Collection`, `for(<Collection` is not Java.

Comment: OMG, this is not code for compile, just an example. I'll be happy if at it at least pring hashcode for me

Comment: Well thank you all, I got it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each time you call `seq.clear()` you empty the inner ArrayList. Don't forget that when you add an object to a Collection, you only add the reference. You don't clone the Object. You should create a new ArrayList Object at each iteration.

E.g.

```
List<Collection<Item>> hull = new ArrayList<Collection<Item>>();
List<Item> seq = new ArrayList<Item>();
seq.add(it1);
hull.add(seq);
List<Item> seq2 = new ArrayList<Item>();
seq2.add(it2)
hull.add(seq2);
```

EDIT:

Complete Sample that compiles:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

public class NewClass1 {

    static class Item {

        String a;

        public Item(String a) {
            this.a = a;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return a;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Collection<Item>> hull = new ArrayList<Collection<Item>>();
        List<Item> seq = new ArrayList<Item>();
        Item it1 = new Item("item 1");
        seq.add(it1);
        hull.add(seq);
        List<Item> seq2 = new ArrayList<Item>();
        Item it2 = new Item("item 2");
        seq2.add(it2);
        hull.add(seq2);

        for (Collection<Item> current : hull) {
            for (Item item : current) {
                System.out.println(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
run:
item 1
item 2
```

Comment: Sounds great, need to check )

Comment: @zest What is the output you get? Could you post a complete minimal program so that we can reproduce the behavior?

Comment: Thanks a lot, creation of new Collection each step helps

Comment: Even cleared, a list is added into the list so first argument is wrong

Comment: Actually proper will be reuse List<Item> seq instead of creation seq2

Comment: Yes this is an example. The point being that you need to create a new object each time. And that if you clear the object, you will be left with a reference to a cleared list.

Answer (score 2):

Your code, corrected to compile:

```
package sample;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Item {
   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      List< List< Item >> hull = new ArrayList<>();
      List< Item >        seq = new ArrayList<>();
      seq.add( new Item());
      hull.add( seq );
      seq = new ArrayList<>(); // in place of seq.clear();
      seq.add( new Item());
      hull.add( seq );
      for( List<Item> c: hull ) {
         System.out.println( c.get( 0 ));
      }
   }
}
```

ouputs:

```
sample.Item@6da264f1
sample.Item@40914272
```

As you can see, there is no problem.

Comment: List< List< Item >> hull = new ArrayList<>(); <<< ---- Very interesting

Comment: Don't know about such shorter way of declaring collections, my example was not for compiling just abstractions, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

In order to iterate through a collection of collections you need a nested foreach.

```
    for(Collection<Item> c: hull)
    {
        for(Item i: c)
        {

        }
    }
```

By the way, are you aware that it1 and it2 are not initialized and that's why you are getting nothing?

size() will always give you the size of the collections, but they might be containing nulls (as it is your case).